# Evaluating $\;\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{3x-1} - \sqrt{x+1}}{x^2-1}$

Tags: limits

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{3x-1} - \sqrt{x+1}}{x^2-1}$$

Can I solve it by taking the largest $x$ coefficient like this?

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{3x-1} - \sqrt{x+1}}{x^2-1}= \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{3x} - \sqrt{x}}{x^2} $

So, the numerator is infinity subtract infinity which cancels out and $ = 0$ , and the denominator $x \to \infty$, so when when $0$ divides by 'any number' or infinity in this case, thus the limit is $0$.

Is this the correct way to evaluate this ?

Or Do I have to multiply by the conjugate to combine the numerator? Like this:

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2}{(x+1) (\sqrt{3x-1} + \sqrt{x+1})}$ , so, $2$ divide by a denominator that is approaching to $\infty$, thus the function approaches $0$ and the limit is $0$?

Which methods is the more correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot say that the limit of infinity minus infinity is zero.  In your example we have $\sqrt{3x}-\sqrt x=(\sqrt 3-1)\sqrt x$ which goes to $+\infty$.  $\infty-\infty$ is indeterminate-it can go to $+\infty, -\infty$ or anything in between.

What you can do is divide through by the highest power of $x$ in the denominator.  In that case the denominator goes to $1$ and the numerator goes to $0$.